# I want to unzip a file that is in parts zip.001, zip.002. PYTHON

Tags: python, zip

I have the following function

```
def descomprime(file_name):
with ZipFile(os.getcwd()+'/descargas/'+file_name, 'r') as zipObject:
    zipObject.extractall()
return print('Archivo extraido con exito...')
```

def descomprime('demo1.zip.001')

and i get this error:

```
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

some idea of how to extract.

Comment: The zip file is either corrupted or its not a zip file, try unzipping it manually using tools.

Comment: Have you tried printing the contents of `os.getcwd()+'/descargas/'+file_name` to see that the path genuinly is the file and check that the file really is a zip file

Comment: I already tried with a normal zip file in the same folder and it works without problem the problem goes when it is a split zip in several zip.001, zip.002